# what is the best way to use firebase auth to generate a JWT that another system can use to auth users?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, jwt, authorization

hi  i'm replacing a legacy auth system and i'd really appreciate a hand with a custom token question!

i'd like to use firebase functions to generate a JWT which can be sent with all HTTPS requests to a legacy system as a means of user authorization (i.e. the legacy system extracts the JWT from the HTTPS request, validates it, and if it passes validation the user is granted access to the requested resource). if i can get this working it will allow me to replace tons of really old auth code on this legacy system with a simple `jwt.verify()` on the `RS256` signature.

i'm currently using an `onCall` firebase function to take a username and password. once i've checked the username and password are all good i generate a custom token using `getAuth().createCustomToken(username, claims)`. i then return that to the client and my frontend code sets it as a cookie so it can be sent with each HTTPS request to the legacy system.

the custom token is created with the default service account `<projectId>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` and so i'm able to get the public key from [here](https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/%3CprojectId%3E-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com).

i read that these keys have a lifespan of 12 hours, so hardcoding this public key into the legacy system for verification will not work.

as it stands i feel like i have the following options:

1. keep fetching the constantly rotating key at the above endpoint
2. create a service account and use those keys instead using `initializeApp({ credential: cert(serviceAccount), ... })`
3. create my own key pair and mint an additional token not through google's SDK
4. use firebase ID tokens instead (and constantly fetch the public keys from [this endpoint](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com))

because of the nature of the legacy system, not needing to fetch keys constantly from an endpoint will be a major benefit.

i feel like i've brainstormed all options, but if you have additional ideas please lmk! otherwise, is there any particular reason to choose (or not choose) one of these options over the others?